# Python web crawling error: transporting the data to DB

Tags: python, database, web-crawler

[Here's the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKhle.png)

import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from DB.model import CrawlingBook
from datetime import datetime

url = "https://www.aladin.co.kr/shop/common/wbest.aspx?BestType=Bestseller&BranchType=1&CID=0&cnt=1000&SortOrder=1&page="
for i in range(1,20):

```
pageUrl = url + str(i)
response = requests.get(pageUrl)
html = response.text


parsedHtml = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
tableList = parsedHtml.select('#Myform .ss_book_box')

for book in tableList:
    imgUrl = book.select('table')[0].select('img')[0].get('src')
    title = book.select('.ss_book_list')[0].select('ul .bo3')[0].text

    
    authorIndex = 1;
    if(book.select('.ss_book_list')[0].select('ul .ss_ht1')):
        authorIndex = 2;
        author = book.select('.ss_book_list')[0].select('ul li')[authorIndex].select('a')[0].text
    else:
        author = book.select('.ss_book_list')[0].select('ul li')[authorIndex].select('a')[0].text
    
    now = datetime.now()

    crawlingBook = CrawlingBook()
    crawlingBook.title = title
    crawlingBook.author_name = author
    crawlingBook.img_url = imgUrl
    crawlingBook.create_at = str(now)
    
print(i, '페이지 크롤링 완료...')
time.sleep(1)
```

I want to crawl the book info(title, author_name, img_url) and check the time when the data was created. But I'm stuck at transporting the data into my DB(MySQL). Any words of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to error, you have not installed pymysql library.

You can do so by

```
pip install PyMySQL
```